# Encontrar a próxima chave de um array

Tags: php, array

Tenho um array que serve de lista de etapas

```
$Lista = ['a','b','c','d'];
```

Preciso encontrar o próximo valor, após indicar o valor atual. 
**Exemplo:**
Estou na etapa B quero que o código me indique a próxima etapa é a C.

**Detalhes:** A minha lista não tem uma ordem ordenada, a qualquer momento eu posso remover ou adicionar uma etapa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lista sempre estará ordenada, se você tem:

```
$Lista = ['a','b','c','d'];
```

É **exatamente** o mesmo que ter:

```
$Lista = [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c', 3 =>'d'];
```

Isso é, mesmo se remover o `c`, o `d` passará a assumir o índice de 2. Se nada tiver ordem, então não tem mágica nenhuma que fará adivinhar qual é a ordem que você quer seguir.

---

Portanto, assumindo que você tenha um código como:

```
$Lista = ['a','b','c','d'];
$PontoAtual = 'c';
```

Se quiser utilizar este dois valores para obter `d` e `b` poderia utilizar o `array_flip`, como:

```
echo $Lista[array_flip($Lista)[$PontoAtual] + 1];
```

Isso daria problemas caso `$PontoAtual` fosse inválido (exemplo: se fosse `x`, que não existe) ou fosse o último valor (por exemplo, se fosse `d`, que é último). Então poderia fazer algo como:

```
$Lista = ['a','b','c','d'];
$PontoAtual = 'c';

$IndiceDoPontoAtual = (array_flip($Lista)[$PontoAtual] ?? false); if ($IndiceDoPontoAtual === false){
    echo "Ponto atual inválido";
    return;
}

$ProximoPonto = $IndiceDoPontoAtual + 1; if(count($Lista) <= $ProximoPonto) {
    echo "O proximo ponto não existe, uma vez que está no último ponto";
    return;
}

printf("O próximo ponto é %s", $Lista[$ProximoPonto]);
```

[Testar.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c82cac4b7213db6ac2511f38fcd2b2e37bac85d)

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda!